# Flutter: How to get multi download url?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

```
Future<List<dynamic>> uploadImage({List<File> images, String Key}) async {
    List<dynamic> imagesUrls = [];

    images.asMap().forEach((index, image) async {
      final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(_getImagePathByHereKey(Key, index: index));
      final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image);
    });

    return imagesUrls;
  }
```

I want to get download url and put it to `imagesUrls`. But `imagesUrls` is empty. How to get download url?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/StorageReference-class.html
There's a method called getDownloadUrl() which returns a Future. I'm assuming that's what you're looking for. I think you use it like this:

```dart
List<dynamic> imagesUrls = images.asMap().entries.map((entry) async {
      final StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(_getImagePathByHereKey(Key, index: entry.key));
      final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(entry.value);
      return await storageReference.getDownloadUrl();
    }).toList();

    return imagesUrls;
```

I think entries.map can't take an async method though so you might wanna use streams. Think you got it from here though.